# Le méchant de Star Wars

Tags: vocabulaire, noms-propres, cinéma

Je ne sais pas comment appeler les protagonistes de la série cinématographique Star Wars. En français, dit-on Darth Vador ou Dark Vador? En anglais, c'est Darth.

Comment: Renaming fictional characters (Darth/Dark Vader) is one thing ... totally normal; but I have several Francophone friends who’d swear on their Mothers’ graves that the last name of the actor Johnny Depp is pronounced **and spelled DEEP**, seriously believing that anyone (including Mr. Depp, himself) who spells it otherwise is doing so in error! But to be fair, many fellow Anglophones misspell & mispronounce the last name of Johnny’s Ex, Vanessa (though I'll admit that I was sad when they parted ways & any news of them getting back together, knee **Deep in Paradise**, would be good news to me).

Comment: @PapaPoule In France, I've never heard it pronounced "Deep". Always "Depp". About spelling, that's an other story... I personnally didn't *know* it was written this way.

Answer (score 5):

En France, il s'appelle "Dark Vador".
En anglais, c'est en effet "Darth Vader".
Au Québec, il semblerait que ce soit "Dark Vador" également.
Il faut aussi noter que le nom des personnages peut évoluer d'un film à l'autre ([source](http://geektonic.fr/star-wars-ses-problemes-de-traduction/))

Comme [Stéphane](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%c3%a9phane-gimenez) dit, en France, on n'aime pas le son anglais "th", c'est difficile à prononcer. Les traducteurs le retirent ou le modifient donc si possible.

Comment: The reason is of course pronuntiation. All the *th*s are removed from titles generally. For example *The Matrix* became *Matrix* in French.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Indeed, I added it to the answer, thanks.